# Why I can rebase but I can't merge in git?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Maybe you can correct me, I'm afraid this might be very simple:

So, from how I understood it git merge and git rebase are 2 different way to accomplish the same goal: therefore if I can rebase I can also merge.

Now, I'm trying to merge *mybranch* with master, but when, from *mybranch*, I do

```
git merge master
```

I got "Already up-to-date", although there are several differences, and when I do

```
git rebase master
```

it start rebasing. Plus, when I fix some conflicts, add the fixed file and do

```
git rebase --continue
```

I got this error:

```
Applying: my commit xxx
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

Here's the current situation:

```
*   179dcec (origin/myBranch, myBranch) Merge branch 'myBranch' of https://github.com/repo/myRepo into myBranch
|\  
| *   ee8525b Merge branch 'myBranch' of https://github.com/repo/myRepo into myBranch
| |\  
| | * 975a4f2  changed the name
| | * 153450b  Fixed jshint problems
| | *   b6eee76 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/repo/myRepo into myBranch
| | |\  
| | * | 70e3139  Fixed a bug
| | * | 715d308  fixed a bug
| | * |   ccfd06a Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/repo/myRepo into myBranch
| | |\ \  
| | * | | 03c87f2  deleted useless test file
| | * | | dd09f21 Testing
| | * | | 214af56  Integrated the unified DB
| | * | |   43242ff Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/repo/myRepo into myBranch
| | |\ \ \  
| | * \ \ \   f9ecae6 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/repo/myRepo into myBranch
| | |\ \ \ \  
| | * | | | | 626bb26  Error handler integrated
| | * | | | |   ac92b60 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/repo/myRepo into myBranch
| | |\ \ \ \ \  
| | * \ \ \ \ \   9f6c0b2 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/repo/myRepo into myBranch
| | |\ \ \ \ \ \  
| | * | | | | | | b09ce40  added DB error handler
| * | | | | | | | d3ebb13  changed the name
| * | | | | | | | f68281e  Fixed jshint problems
| * | | | | | | | 31cb0b3  Fixed a bug
| * | | | | | | | 74d8735  fixed a bug
| * | | | | | | | cb3e6e2  deleted file
| * | | | | | | | 80d7164 Testing
| * | | | | | | | 191fb77  Integrated the unified DB
| * | | | | | | | 2af7142  Error handler integrated
| * | | | | | | | fff8b2f  added DB error handler
| | |_|_|_|_|_|/  
| |/| | | | | |  
* | | | | | | | 730b412  deleted useless test file
```

What's going on here?

Comment: If you're trying to merge `master` with `mybranch` then you need to do the merge when you're sitting on your master branch. Therefore `git checkout master` and then `git merge mybranch`

Comment: Not sure, is this on github or somewhere I can look at it?

Comment: @aus_lacy the OP is trying to merge master into mybranch, that's different.

Comment: @djechlin well the wording `mybranch with master` introduces some amount of ambiguity. However, the reason `rebase` seems to work is because when you specify a branch upon rebase `git` automatically does a `git checkout specfied_branch` before doing anything else.

Comment: Please post the output from `git log --graph --decorate --oneline    mybranch master`

Comment: aus_lacy I wrote 'from mybranch', but sorry you're right, it was not super clear. djechlin Sorry, it is not a public repo

@jthill [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/S15RWrad)

Answer (score 0):

> from how I understood it git merge and git rebase are 2 different way to accomplish the same goal: therefore if I can rebase I can also merge

It's true that rebase and merge will (assuming any merge conflicts get resolved the same ways) wind up with the same content at the resulting tip -- but rebase makes a new commit for each rebased commit, sequentially replaying the changes in each on the new base commit's content (`master` here).  Merge leaves the current history just as it is, and adds a new commit with the changes in all the commits on each branch since the merge base combined into just that one new one.

This is easier to understand if you keep in mind that each commit is of full content: for merge, git is just diffing the tip of the left branch against the merge base, diffing the tip of the right branch against the merge base, combining all the hunks that look independent, and leaving you to sort out any hunks that look like they might conflict.  It's exactly the same diff/patch sequence you'd do yourself if you had to.

So you can think of rebase as a *retroactive* merge.

Answer (score 0):

If the branch you are trying to merge is already merged, you will get "Already up-to-date". If you rebase, you will take all commits and re-create them on the target.

Let's visualize:

```
A-B-C-D  --master
  `-E-F  --feature
```

If on feature and you merge master, i.e. `git checkout feature && git merge master`, you will get the following new history with `M` being the new merge commit:

```
A-B-C-D.   --master
  `-E-F-M  --feature
```

Running `git merge master` *again* does nothing, because master is already fully contained in your feature branch.

However, if you now run `git rebase master` (which rebases your branch *onto* master, not master into your branch), all commits of feature not on master will be recreated on top of master. `git rebase X` is almost equivalent to `git rebase --onto X X your-current-branch`. Result:

```
A-B-C-D.         --master
        `-E'-F'  --feature
```

There's no additional merge commit, but the original commits `E` and `F` are gone (i.e. are no longer reachable through any ref). `E'` and `F'` are copies of the original commits. They have the same patch, i.e. still apply the same change to your source code, but a different commit hash. Why? Because their parent commit(s) is/are different and their committer time is newer.